# Upgrade from 10.04 to 16.04

Tags: 10.04

Yes, not a typo. 10.04 to 16.04

If I attempt to do this am I going to lose data and software? I have backed up my files to a portable hard drive, but what about emails and address book in evolution 2.28.3 I have copied my bookmarks to be hard drive as well.

I am a bit of a newbie to this and talk of 'command' lines' makes me nervous. I have downloaded 16.04 do I just install it.

What are the gotchas I need to know about?

Comment: There's an easy way that keeps data but not installed software.

Answer (score 1):

the short answer is NO. Ubuntu normally allows only to upgrade from one version to the next, i.e. 10.04 to 10.10. or as 10.04 is a LTS versions to 12.04 LTS. 
So you may try , in 3 steps, upgrade to 12.04LTS, upgrade then to 14.04 LTS, upgrade then to 16.04LTS. 
Alternative, wipe your HD and start the 16.04 LTS instalation.

Do not count on your files, etc come with it, but you made a backup already, OK
Also your emails and address book need a back-up to be sure they will survive; I donot know how, as I do not use evolution. 
see also [Can I skip over releases when upgrading?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/34430/can-i-skip-over-releases)